# How to Impersonate Windows user when using Windows Authentication to remote SQL Server?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, security, windows-authentication

I have setup an ASP.NET application on a Windows 2012 server and a SQL Server 2012 instance on another Windows 2012 server. I want to use Windows Authentication to connect to the SQL server due to security reasons.

There is a Windows user IUSRSQL, which has been added to the SQL Server and can access the relevant database tables and the data.

My connection string is:

```
Server=DB-SERVER;Database=MY-DB;Trusted_Connection=True;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True
```

How do I tell IIS to connect to the SQL server as IUSRSQL?

The ASP.NET application is using Forms authentication for its users.

Is this configuration secure?

Thanks

Comment: Add User ID=IUSRSQL;Password=[IUSRSQLpassword], Is this what you mean?

Comment: That is SQL Server authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add the IIS Application Pool account to the SQL Server, or alternatively set the credentials of IIS Application Pool account to match the Windows identity you have created in SQL Server.

Comment: How do I change the IIS Application Pool account to use IUSRSQL?

Comment: Go into IIS Manager, find the Application Pool that is bound to your Virtual Directory and change the Application Pool Identity. Link to the instructions is here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771170(v=ws.10).aspx